# Unclosed character literal

Tags: java

```
// Create a class called Dog containing two String: name and says. In main(), create two dogs objects
and assign it to spot's object.  

class Dog {
    String name;
    String says;
}

public class DogSays {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Dog D1 = new Dog();
        Dog D2 = new Dog();

        D1.says = "Woof!";
        D1.name = "Scruffy!";

        D2.says = "Bark!";
        D2.name = "Spot!";
        System.out.println("Hi! My name is " + D1.name);
        System.out.println(D1.says);
        System.out.println("Rooooooooowr! I'm " + D2.name);
        System.out.println(D2.says);
    }
}
```

I've been checking this for an hour and I don't have any idea what's wrong. I get a class, enum, or interface error expected and also a unclosed character literal. I think it' something with the quotes.

Comment: The code you've given compiles...

Comment: Your code is working just fine, what is the issue? can you post the error??

Comment: I get output as `Hi! My name is Scruffy!
Woof!
Rooooooooowr! I'm Spot!
Bark!`

Comment: not when i try...i've been going over this all night

Comment: The comment from line 2?

Comment: and no it's not homework...i'm not even taking a java class atm

Comment: So, do you get any errors? Please post the *exact* error message.

Comment: if you have copied the code from somewhere else to your IDE, check the quotes, replace them with your platform's quotes. it is a simple compile error message, by googling you could solve it, spending 1 hour for that is something horrible.

Comment: "and assign it to spot's object. " this should be the part of top comment as well.

Comment: i dont see any error in this class.

Comment: OK, what are the steps that you are following?? What error you get for the respective step??

Comment: change `and assign it to spot's object.` with `// and assign it to spot's object.` and see if any error comes...

Comment: The answer is below by Costis Aivalis. Avoid copy pasting

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem "Unclosed character literal" is here:

```
//Exercise2.5 Create a class called Dog containing two String: name and says. In main(), create two dogs objects
and assign it to spot's object.
```

Make it:

```
//Exercise2.5 Create a class called Dog containing two String: name and says. In main(), create two dogs objects
//and assign it to spot's object.
```

You can not have stray comments without leading `//` or not enclosed in `/*`  and `*/` pairs...

Answer (score 1):

The only thing that comes to mind is this:

```
//Exercise2.5 Create a class called Dog containing two String: name and says. In main(), create two dogs objects
and assign it to spot's object.
```

If that is exactly how you have written it in your class, then, you will get an error on your second line of your comment, being: `and assign it to spot's object.`. In Java, `//` denotes one line comments, so you will have to either do this:

```
//Exercise2.5 Create a class called Dog containing two String: name and says. In main(), create two dogs objects
//and assign it to spot's object.
```

or this

```
/*Exercise2.5 Create a class called Dog containing two String: name and says. In main(), create two dogs objects
and assign it to spot's object.  */
```

As opposed to `//` which instructs the compiler that any other text which follows the `//` and is on the same line to be ignored since they are comments, the `/* */` characters denote comment blocks which can span any number of lines.